# Treat rows as instances of a externally defined Class?

Tags: python, class, pandas, row

I have a Class Blah. Then I instantiate thousands of objects which I store in array. I would like to store it in a pandas data frame.
I can easily convert the array to df, that is not a problem. But is a waste!

What I would like to do is treat every row in the DF as a separate object of the class Blah. This way I can create my own methods that do more sophisticated manipulations.

f.e.:

```
for row in df :
   row.blah_method()
```

Is there a way to treat every row as externally defined class.

---

This seem like the best case with what I have !!

```
class Blah:

   def __init__(self, row):
      self.row = row

   def say(self) : print self.row


for row in df.iterrows() : Blah(row).say()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're out of luck on the `pd.DataFrame` because a `pd.DataFrame` is a `pd.Series` of `pd.Series`.  Every column is interpreted as another `pd.Series`.  Without this, well, the whole concept of `pd.DataFrame` breaks....

However!  You can use `pd.Series` to do what you want.  Consider my toy `class` and how we can use it in a Series.

```
class blah(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.value = i

    def __add__(self, other):
        return blah(self.value + 2 * other.value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def blah_method(self):
        return "Look at me <<<{}>>>".format(self.value)

a = blah(1)
b = blah(3)

a + b

7
```

Now let's make a `pd.Series`

```
s = pd.Series([blah(1), blah(3), blah(-4), blah(7)])

s.sum()

13
```

And! Look at the type of the `sum`

```
type(s.sum())

__main__.blah
```

Using `apply`

```
s.apply(blah.blah_method)

0     Look at me <<<1>>>
1     Look at me <<<3>>>
2    Look at me <<<-4>>>
3     Look at me <<<7>>>
dtype: object
```

Iterating

```
for k, v in s.iteritems():
    print(v.blah_method())

Look at me <<<1>>>
Look at me <<<3>>>
Look at me <<<-4>>>
Look at me <<<7>>>
```

Comment: I see your point. it sucks cause i want to use other DF functionality.

Comment: @user1019129 feel free to up vote if this was useful.  Also, ask questions with specifics of what you want to do.